# Selecting random cells and storing them in range variable in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, range, selection, formula

```
Sub selecting() 
Dim r as Range
Set r = Application.Selection
MsgBox r.Cells(1,1).Address(false,false)
MsgBox r.Cells(1,2).Address(false,false)
MsgBox r.Cells(2,1).Address(false,false)
End Sub
```

Now the thing is,  I select some random cells as irregular range in excel sheet. I get first cell address correct but the next cell address is the cell neighbor to the first one,  and not the next cell that I selected.

Basically,  I want to collect values from irregular ranges into an array.  It would be really helpful if I get addresses of each cell selected in this irregular range.

**Simply saying, what I want is if I select cells e1,g4,d7,r1,t3 I should get an array of only these 5 cells in vba program, and this array should have no access to other cells apart from those that were selected.**

Answer (score 0):

I am a little unclear on exactly what you are attempting, but I believe this may help you understand the behavior of the script as it's running.

```
Sub selecting()

    Dim myArray(0 To 100, 0 To 1) As Variant

    Dim rngSelected As Range
    Set rngSelected = Application.Selection

    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In rngSelected

        Dim counter As Integer
        Debug.Print "The value of cell " & counter & " is " & rng.Value & _
            " , and the address is " & rng.Address(False, False)

        myArray(counter, 0) = rng.Value
        myArray(counter, 1) = rng.Address(False, False)
        counter = counter + 1

    Next rng

End Sub
```

Maybe you can tweak this until you get the behavior you are looking for?

Comment: Once selected range has been stored in a range variable, I want to gather the addresses of the cells selected. For eg : I selected D4, F2, G7.... Then I should be able to get an array from which I can access only these selected cells and not others. While what is happening is the range variable is storing all cells starting from D4. That means, if I access range.cells(1,1).Address(false,false) it gives D4, but when I try range.cells(2,1).Address(false,false) it gives D5 although it should have given me only values that I selected. I never selected D5.